# TikZ decoration markings not on the path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-decorations, bezier

My
question
is
related
to
TikZ
Decoration [markings](https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#autosec-5525)

While compiling the code, there are no errors
[TeXLive.net](https://texlive.net/run?%5Cdocumentclass%5Btikz%5D%7Bstandalone%7D%0A%5Cbegin%7Bdocument%7D%0A%5Cusetikzlibrary%7Bdecorations.markings%7D%0A%5Cbegin%7Btikzpicture%7D%0A%5Cdraw%5Bpreaction=%7Bdecorate%7D,decoration=%7Bmarkings,%0Amark=at%20position%200.15%20with%20%5Carrow%7Blatex%7D,%0Amark=at%20position%200.25%20with%20%5Carrow%7Blatex%7D,%0Amark=at%20position%200.35%20with%20%5Carrow%7Blatex%7D,%0Amark=at%20position%200.45%20with%20%5Carrow%7Blatex%7D,%0Amark=at%20position%200.55%20with%20%5Carrow%7Blatex%7D,%0Amark=at%20position%200.65%20with%20%5Carrow%7Blatex%7D,%0Amark=at%20position%200.2%20with%20%7B%5Cfill(0,0)circle(0.1);%7D,%20%25%20should%20be%20on%20the%20curve%E2%9D%93%0Amark=at%20position%200.3%20with%20%7B%5Cfill(0,0)circle(0.1);%7D,%20%25%20should%20be%20on%20the%20curve%E2%9D%93%0Amark=at%20position%200.4%20with%20%7B%5Cfill(0,0)circle(0.1);%7D,%20%25%20on%20the%20curve%E2%9C%94%EF%B8%8F%0Amark=at%20position%200.5%20with%20%7B%5Cfill(0,0)circle(0.1);%7D,%20%25%20on%20the%20curve%E2%9C%94%EF%B8%8F%0Amark=at%20position%200.6%20with%20%7B%5Cfill(0,0)circle(0.1);%7D,%20%25%20on%20the%20curve%E2%9C%94%EF%B8%8F%0Amark=at%20position%200.7%20with%20%7B%5Cfill(0,0)circle(0.1);%7D,%20%25%20on%20the%20curve%E2%9C%94%EF%B8%8F%0A%7D%5D(-4.5,-0.5)%20..%20controls%20(-3,2)%20and%20(-1,2)%20..%20(-0.5,-0.5)..%20controls%20(0,-3)%20and%20(3,-5)%20..%20(4,2.5);%0A%5Cend%7Btikzpicture%7D%0A%5Cend%7Bdocument%7D)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[preaction={decorate},decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.15 with \arrow{latex},
mark=at position 0.25 with \arrow{latex},
mark=at position 0.35 with \arrow{latex},
mark=at position 0.45 with \arrow{latex},
mark=at position 0.55 with \arrow{latex},
mark=at position 0.65 with \arrow{latex},
mark=at position 0.2 with {\fill(0,0)circle(0.1);}, % should be on the curve❓
mark=at position 0.3 with {\fill(0,0)circle(0.1);}, % should be on the curve❓
mark=at position 0.4 with {\fill(0,0)circle(0.1);}, % on the curve✔️
mark=at position 0.5 with {\fill(0,0)circle(0.1);}, % on the curve✔️
mark=at position 0.6 with {\fill(0,0)circle(0.1);}, % on the curve✔️
mark=at position 0.7 with {\fill(0,0)circle(0.1);}, % on the curve✔️
}](-4.5,-0.5) .. controls (-3,2) and (-1,2) .. (-0.5,-0.5).. controls (0,-3) and (3,-5) .. (4,2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The path is concatenation of 2 Bezier curves.

First I put some arrows on the path, then I put some black dots on the path, however the first few black dots aren‘t on the path.

I tried another way:
While compiling the code, there are no errors
[TeXLive.net](https://texlive.net/run?%5Cdocumentclass%5Btikz%5D%7Bstandalone%7D%0A%5Cbegin%7Bdocument%7D%0A%5Cusetikzlibrary%7Bdecorations.markings%7D%0A%5Cbegin%7Btikzpicture%7D%0A%5Cdraw%5Bpreaction=%7Bdecorate%7D,decoration=%7Bmarkings,%0Amark=at%20position%200.2%20with%20%7B%5Cfill(0,0)circle(0.1);%7D,%0Amark=at%20position%200.3%20with%20%7B%5Cfill(0,0)circle(0.1);%7D,%0Amark=at%20position%200.4%20with%20%7B%5Cfill(0,0)circle(0.1);%7D,%0Amark=at%20position%200.5%20with%20%7B%5Cfill(0,0)circle(0.1);%7D,%0Amark=at%20position%200.6%20with%20%7B%5Cfill(0,0)circle(0.1);%7D,%0Amark=at%20position%200.7%20with%20%7B%5Cfill(0,0)circle(0.1);%7D,%0Amark=at%20position%200.15%20with%20%5Carrow%7Blatex%7D,%20%25%20should%20be%20on%20the%20curve%E2%9D%93%0Amark=at%20position%200.25%20with%20%5Carrow%7Blatex%7D,%20%25%20should%20be%20on%20the%20curve%E2%9D%93%0Amark=at%20position%200.35%20with%20%5Carrow%7Blatex%7D,%20%25%20should%20be%20on%20the%20curve%E2%9D%93%0Amark=at%20position%200.45%20with%20%5Carrow%7Blatex%7D,%20%25%20on%20the%20curve%E2%9C%94%EF%B8%8F%0Amark=at%20position%200.55%20with%20%5Carrow%7Blatex%7D,%20%25%20on%20the%20curve%E2%9C%94%EF%B8%8F%0Amark=at%20position%200.65%20with%20%5Carrow%7Blatex%7D,%20%25%20on%20the%20curve%E2%9C%94%EF%B8%8F%0A%7D%5D(-4.5,-0.5)%20..%20controls%20(-3,2)%20and%20(-1,2)%20..%20(-0.5,-0.5)..%20controls%20(0,-3)%20and%20(3,-5)%20..%20(4,2.5);%0A%5Cend%7Btikzpicture%7D%0A%5Cend%7Bdocument%7D)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[preaction={decorate},decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.2 with {\fill(0,0)circle(0.1);},
mark=at position 0.3 with {\fill(0,0)circle(0.1);},
mark=at position 0.4 with {\fill(0,0)circle(0.1);},
mark=at position 0.5 with {\fill(0,0)circle(0.1);},
mark=at position 0.6 with {\fill(0,0)circle(0.1);},
mark=at position 0.7 with {\fill(0,0)circle(0.1);},
mark=at position 0.15 with \arrow{latex}, % should be on the curve❓
mark=at position 0.25 with \arrow{latex}, % should be on the curve❓
mark=at position 0.35 with \arrow{latex}, % should be on the curve❓
mark=at position 0.45 with \arrow{latex}, % on the curve✔️
mark=at position 0.55 with \arrow{latex}, % on the curve✔️
mark=at position 0.65 with \arrow{latex}, % on the curve✔️
}](-4.5,-0.5) .. controls (-3,2) and (-1,2) .. (-0.5,-0.5).. controls (0,-3) and (3,-5) .. (4,2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

First I put some black dots on the path, then I put some arrows on the path, however the first few arrows aren‘t on the path.

Comment: Interesting thing is that if you comment those lines with circle marks, the arrows are correctly placed.

Comment: Multiple `mark=at position <pos> with <code>` must have their `<pos>` in increasing order, see doc for this option: https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#pgf/decoration/mark. "It is possible to give the `mark` option several times, which causes several markings to be applied. In this case, however, it is necessary that the positions on the path are in increasing order."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason, if you put the first marks in the correct order, they all belong to their correct places. This I can't explain yet, but at least, it works.

### EDIT

Adding @muzimuzhi comment about that:

> Multiple `mark=at position <pos> with <code>` must have their `<pos>` in increasing order, see doc for this option: [tikz.dev/library-decorations#pgf/decoration/mark](https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#pgf/decoration/mark).
>
> > It is possible to give the `mark` option several times, which causes several markings to be applied. In this case, however, it is necessary that the positions on the path are in increasing order.

The strange behaviour here lies in the fact that the last ones are *not* in increasing order, and yet seem to be correctly placed.
[image: marks (not) on curve]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[preaction={decorate},decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.15 with \arrow{latex},
mark=at position 0.2 with {\fill(0,0)circle(0.1);},
mark=at position 0.25 with \arrow{latex},
mark=at position 0.3 with {\fill(0,0)circle(0.1);},
mark=at position 0.35 with \arrow{latex},
mark=at position 0.4 with {\fill(0,0)circle(0.1);},
mark=at position 0.5 with {\fill(0,0)circle(0.1);},
mark=at position 0.6 with {\fill(0,0)circle(0.1);},
mark=at position 0.7 with {\fill(0,0)circle(0.1);},
mark=at position 0.45 with \arrow{latex},
mark=at position 0.55 with \arrow{latex},
mark=at position 0.65 with \arrow{latex},
}](-4.5,-0.5) .. controls (-3,2) and (-1,2) .. (-0.5,-0.5).. controls (0,-3) and (3,-5) .. (4,2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```